# How to get total percent distribution out of 100% for the underlying denominator for each column in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I have simple function of calculating the sum of numbers and strings in columns in a table. The sum works well and gives me correct results. The issue is that whenever I try to divide the total sum of each column with 100 I end up with wrong values

Scenario A

I have a sum of `969.35` in column A, whenever I divide the value with `100` I expect to get `9.69` but I end up with `0.51` . Am not sure why this is being calculated as so.

This is my implementation of getting the sum

```
getSum(columnNumber) {
    let sum = 0;
    const columnNumberToPropertyMap = [
      "id",
      "teamNumber",
      "rural",
      "completed",
      "entirehouseholdabsent",
      "postponed",
      "refused",
      "vacant",
      "dwelling"     
    ];
    const property = columnNumberToPropertyMap[columnNumber];
    return this.rural.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      //const adder = Number(curr[property]) || 0;
      const adder = isNaN(Number(curr[property])) ? 0 : Number(curr[property]);
      sum = acc + adder
      return sum;
    }, 0).toFixed(2);
  }
```

the above code works well as I can get the sum of each coiumn.

How I am trying to get the percentage

```
 getSum(columnNumber) {
        let sum = 0;
        let percentage = 0;
        const columnNumberToPropertyMap = [
          "id",
          "teamNumber",
          "rural",
          "completed",
          "entirehouseholdabsent",
          "postponed",
          "refused",
          "vacant",
          "dwelling"     
        ];
        const property = columnNumberToPropertyMap[columnNumber];
        return this.rural.reduce((acc, curr) => {
          //const adder = Number(curr[property]) || 0;
          const adder = isNaN(Number(curr[property])) ? 0 : Number(curr[property]);
          sum = acc + adder
          percentage = (sum)/100;
          return percentage ;
        }, 0).toFixed(2);
      }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this it will be fine. You are dividing each time  which is causing issue.
Percentage should be outside of reduce loop.

```
(this.rural.reduce((acc, curr) => {
          //const adder = Number(curr[property]) || 0;
          const adder = isNaN(Number(curr[property])) ? 0 : Number(curr[property]);
          sum = acc + adder
          percentage = sum;
          return percentage ;
        }, 0) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per angular standards, using `Number() && String()` is not a good practice.

When you take a value from a formControl, you can take it like this:

```
const wholeFormValue = this.formName.getRawValue();
```

The above line will give you a JSON object, something like:

```
{formCtrl1: ctrl1Value, formCtrl2: ctrl2Value, ......etc}
```

Now, if you want a particular formControlValue, you can do this:

```
this.formName.get('formControlName').value
```

You need to make sure that, that particular field (i hope thats an input field) accepts only numbers so that you can also get only numbers in the `this.formName.get('formControlName').value`.

IF YOU ARE NOT A FAN OF DOING LIKE THAT, please use `parseInt() or parseFloat()`
rather than `Number()`

When you use parseInt() and parseFloat() you will get the exact number values.

Comment: Hi @Srikar, it is json data and it has string and number